# why is apt not able to locate the package once ran via script?

Tags: apt, bash, scripts

I have this Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine (vagrant) which I'm trying to append packages to with the following shell script

> apt e.g.

```
firefox
flux
libimage-exiftool-perl 
perl-doc
vlc
wireshark
automake
openvpn
postgresql
telnet
tmux
wget
```

> setup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update -y
sudo apt upgrade -y
cat software/apt | while read line 
do
sudo apt-get install -y "$line"
done
```

aswell as similar approaches for snaps and adding .deb packages followed by dist-upgrade.

Running the script returns

```
 default: E: Unable to locate package firefox
```

Installing the packages manually, works fine.

Why? I'm trying to deploy a set of packages. How would you approach this?

Comment: Can you please include a few complete verbatim error messages (not obfuscated with `...`). Did you create the `software/apt` in a Windows text editor?

Comment: I've edited the Question, ... is the package name. All files were created on windows, within VSCode.